# Dojo datagrid - Retrieve value for field of each column.

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo, field

I'm currently using a dojo datagrid and I want to be able to loop through a list containing all the value for each field of the grid. For example say my grid has these columns:

```
      <th field="name" width="200px">Name</th>
      <th field="description" width="200px">Description</th>
          <th field="type" width="200px">Type</th>
```

How do I get a list of all the field values? With this example, the list should be [name, description, type]. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this.

First, you need to know the ID of the dijit.  If it's autogenerated (because you are declaring your DataGrid in HTML), you may need to use `dojo.query` to find the DOM node, and use `dijit.byNode(node)` to locate the dijit.  The example below assumes you know the ID.

```
var fields = [];
var getFields = function(object) {
    // recurse to handle stacked rows
    if(dojo.isArray(object)) {
        dojo.forEach(object, function(o) {
            getFields(o);
        });
    } else if(object.field) {
        fields.push(object.field);
    } else if(object.cells) {
        getFields(object.cells);
    }
};
var structure = dijit.byId("dojox_grid_DataGrid_0").structure;
getFields(structure);
console.log(fields);
```

This will recursively process the structure of the Grid, looking for any object with a `field` property.

**Update** I had to add in a check for `object.cells` for declarative grids.